# Does CapitolOne reward program or AMEX reward points have an API?

Tags: api, credit-card, payment-processing, reward

Is there a programmatic way to access reward programs of multiple credit cards and airlines?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is inappropriate for this site; first, it's entirely too vague; second, the answer would depend on the exact card, program, issuer, and other localized details. This is a question you need to ask card companies or issuing banks. SO isn't a replacement for vendor support. You might want to take a few minutes to review the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) in order to become more familiar with the types of questions that are proper to ask here. Making sure things stay on-topic is one of the ways that SO remains a great programming resource. :-)

Comment: @Ken I agree that the question is overly broad, but there is a single source for this, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's not easy to implement, but the Yodlee API allows you to connect to almost any financial data source in the world: http://www.yodlee.com/solutions-developer.html